# Visual studio thinks my project is up-to-date

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, build

So, I have a template function in my C++ header files, and when I make changes to it, Visual Studio 2013 still thinks that the project is up-to-date. So when i run my project, it runs like I didn't make any changes.

I can replicate this situation with any header file and template function, and only way to resolve it seems to be rebuilding. Is this just a bug in Visual Studio or do I have some settings wrong?

Comment: are you trying to rebuild the solution or just the project that declares the template? if it's the latter you need to build the projects that use the templates which I would expect visual studio to detect

Comment: Well, I only reference to these templates In the same project that they are declared. Rebuilding that project solves the problem, but it compiles every file of the project, which takes a lot of time. Normally i just run the project with (sift) f5, and VS compiles every file that has been chanced.

Comment: could be a bug perhaps but it's a common mistake (at least with me) that when I change the template declaration that I don't compile the template instantiations

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't see how this can be the user's fault. It should detect every change automatically.